# How to add to specific index of an array

Tags: python

I'm new to python so excuse me but all I'm trying to do is add to a number to a specific index of an array. This should be fairly basic, I have simplified code to understand the problem.

Why wouldn't this work?

```
x = [0] * 10
print(x)
x[2] + 1 
print(x)
```

Actual results

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Expected results

> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: assign the new value x[2]   = x[2] + 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to assign to the slice:

```
x[2] = x[2] + 1
```

or

```
x[2] += 1
```